# Query a Chart with C3.js

Tags: d3.js, visualization, data-visualization, c3.js

I created a simple pie chart with around 10 items (using **C3.js and D3.js**). Now, in a second visualization (a table) I want to know the colors of each of the items, to also represent them in the table.

Is it possible to **query the chart to receive the item's name and color**?

I know I can manually [hardcode colors](http://c3js.org/samples/data_color.html) for items and just use the same colors. However, this is not applicable in my case, as the items in the **pie chart vary greatly** (and I don't know them yet, as it is dependent on the user), hence my question.

Comment: It's probably using one of [D3's colour scales](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#category10).

Comment: A very good point, thank you. Probably `d3.scale.category10`, as I limit the chart to 10 items. The problem is it seems to use these colors randomly rather than always the same order...

Comment: The first colour will be mapped to the first datum and so on. It should be deterministic with respect to the order of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick look at the source code reveals that you are correct, it's a [category10()](https://github.com/masayuki0812/c3/blob/931109f8269688b8d623b4523335670dd813b4dc/src/color.js#L4).

Further it retrieves them by a key of "data id", which appears to be the first "column" in it's data input format:

```
columns: [
  ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250], //<-- data1 is id
  ['data2', 130, 340, 200, 500, 250, 350]
]
```

You can inspect which are used by:

```
> chart.internal.color('data1')
  "#1f77b4"
> chart.internal.color('data2')
  "#ff7f0e"
```